# Redirect output to file, then redirect to console in Linux

Tags: c, linux, redirect, input, output

I have code. It redirects output to file. How I can return output to console? I tried to do it, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   int save1 = dup(1);
   int fd = open("my_test.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0666);
   if (fd == -1) {}
   dup2(fd, 1);
   printf("to file");
   close(fd);

   dup2(save1, 1);
   close(save1);
   printf("to console");

}
```

Comment: What did you try that doesn't work? Share more code that you are trying.

Comment: I want to call function printf("to console"). It must print string into the console. But first, I want to call code which I wrote before.

Comment: Share the complete program.

Comment: Is writing to file and then writing the same again to console an option?

Comment: Is only outputting to stdout an option? You could then use the tool `tee`.

Comment: I didn't understand you.. I just want to redirect the output to a file then redirect the output to the console. The string "to file" must be written to a file. The string "to console" must be written to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from buffering.

Simply adding calls to `fflush( stdout )` does the trick.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
   int saved1 = dup(1);
   int fd = open("my_test.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0666);
   dup2(fd, 1);
   close(fd);

   printf("to file\n");

   fflush(stdout);
   dup2(saved1, 1);
   close(saved1);

   printf("to console\n");
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && ./a
to console

$ cat my_test.txt
to file
```